# Getting the weekday for a certain day in the next 6 months

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the weekday of the 21st of the next 6 months in PHP?

For example, say the 21st falls on a Tuesday next month, then I want "Tuesday" to be returned. But I want this for each of the next 6 months. What is the most elegant solution to this?

Comment: Do you want all tuesdays or all days of the 21st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that will give you the expected result:

```
// starting date
$date = new DateTime('2012-08-21');

// iterate for 6 months
for ($i = 0; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d').' : '.$date->format('l') . PHP_EOL;
    $date->modify('+1 month');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) classes are super-handy for this sort of thing.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d', 21);
$period = new DatePeriod($date, new DateInterval('P1M'), 6, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
foreach ($period as $day) {
    echo $day->format('M jS => l'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Now you're just plain copying!

Comment: `$day = 21; $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( '!Y-m-d', date('Y') . '-' . date('m') . '-' . $day, new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));`

Comment: @nickb ewww! But that gives me an idea.

Comment: @salathe I was just being excessive, like this: For God sakes man, throw a Timezone in there before we all explode! :D

Comment: Some of us use `date.timezone` with a sensible value.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this:

```
$date = 21;
$year = 2012;
$month = date('m'); // Get current month
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
    if($month == 13)
    {
        $year++;
        $month=1;
    }
    $day = date('l',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$date,$year));
    echo "$month $date falls on $day<br />\n";
    $month++;
}
```

Comment: I did have them backwards, didn't I? Long day at work ;-) It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify("first day of this month");
$date->modify("+20 days"); //21st
echo $date->format("F: l (Y-m-d)") . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $date->modify("+1 month");
    echo $date->format("F: l (Y-m-d)") . PHP_EOL;
}
```